# Ember route method when landing only on route view

Tags: ember.js

When a user lands on my `/settings` page, I want to redirect them to `/settings/overview`. How can I accomplish this *only* when they land on `/settings`, but not fire when they land on, for example, `/settings/account`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `SettingsIndexRoute` and redirect when they hit that route.  The index route will only be hit when you hit the root of the resource.

```
App.SettingsIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(){
    // I'm assuming overview is a route under settings
    // and not a resource under it
    this.transitionTo('settings.overview'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm using ember-cli so created a /routes/settings/index.js file and added this - worked great.